# How to bind current image to update form field with Laravel?

Tags: php, image, laravel, image-upload

Here is my update form, but I am using it as a partial, I wanted to embed current image to the file field which is named as "thumbnail". Can any one tell me how can I take the current image if a new image is not selected to the file field. And how to include the date from database value?

```
{!! Form::model($article, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'files' => true, 'action' =>['ArticlesController@update', $article->id]]) !!}

<!-- Form thumbnail  Input -->
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('thumbnail', 'Thumbnail:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
    @if($article->thumbnail)
        <div class="col-xs-2 thumb">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="/images/tn-{{$article->thumbnail}}"
                     alt="{{$article->titlel}}">
            </a>
        </div>
    @endif

        {!! Form::file('thumbnail', null, ['class' => 'form-control file']) !!}

</div>
<br>
<!-- Form body Input -->
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('body', 'Body:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
    {!! Form::textarea('body', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

<!-- Form published_at Input -->
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('published_at', 'Published:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
    {!! Form::input('date', 'published_at', date('Y-m-d'), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

<!-- Form Update Article  Input -->
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::submit($submitButtonText, ['class' => 'form-control btn btn-info pull-right']) !!}
</div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: I find your question very unclear. Please elaborate what your issue is and what the expected behavior should be.

Comment: Luceos, sorry for my poor english. what I am trying to say is; when I go to edit the record, with form model binding, it takes all the data from my database, but image data is not bind to form file filed, but the as you can see, I have a preview of the current image above the field. What I want to do is to embed that image to file field if an image is not set. I hope you are little clear now. Thank you.

Comment: You want to populate the File field with the uploaded image if there is one?

Comment: When updating the file field in the controller, check if use image was uploaded. If new image was uploaded, add the new value in the field and update the model. If new image was not uploaded, don't update the model.

Comment: @karanmhatre can you please show me the example code for this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

About the date part of the question

```
    {!! Form::input('date', 'published_at', $article->published_at, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

PS: I would recommend, if there is no other logic behind, to use the default created_at field instead of published_at.

Comment: It didn't just output any value, but as it is html5 date field, it just output dd/mm/yy to that field.